# What Im I missing in this code

Tags: java

This code is supposed to be able to read a users input and do any of the options in the menu choice, What Im I missing? Sample outputs are

Enter a sample text:
We'll continue our quest in space.

You entered: We'll continue our quest in space.
MENU
c - Number of non-whitespace characters
w - Number of words
f - Find text
r - Replace all !'s
s - Shorten spaces
q - Quit

Choose an option:
c
Number of non-whitespace characters: 6

```
   import java.util.Scanner

    public class AuthoringAssistant {
    public static void main(String [] args) { 
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
    String mainString = "";

    System.out.println("Enter a sample text:");
    mainString = scnr.nextLine();


    System.out.print("You entered: ");
    System.out.println(mainString);

    return mainString;
  }

  public static void printMenu(){

      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

      char menuChoice = '?';

      String inputString="";

      while(menuChoice != 'q'){
        System.out.println("MENU");
        System.out.println("c - Number of non-whitespace characters");
        System.out.println("w - Number of words");
        System.out.println("f - Find text");
        System.out.println("r - Replace all !'s");
        System.out.println("s - Shorten spaces");
        System.out.println("q - Quit");

        menuChoice = scnr.next().charAt(0);


        if(menuChoice == 'c'){
            getNumOfNonWSCharacters();


        }else if(menuChoice == 'w'){
            getNumOfWords();

        }else if(menuChoice == 'f'){
            findText();

        }else if(menuChoice == 'r'){
            replaceExclamation();

        }else if(menuChoice == 's'){
            shortenSpace();
        }
      }
  return;
  }

}
```

Comment: "What am I missing in this code" is not a proper question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: why do you think you are missing something?

Comment: a call to `printMenu()` ...

Comment: Well Im not getting an output from any of the if and else if statements, I was thinking probably I had to add on a "System.out.print();" But I dont know exactly what would go inside the parentheses

Answer (score 0):

You never called the method `printMenu()` in the main... so it can't do much than

```
Enter a sample text: We'll continue our quest in space.
You entered: We'll continue our quest in space.
```

Just add the line

```
public static void main(String [] args) { 
    ...
    printMenu();
}
```

But you should share the `Scanner` instead of instanciate two.

And remove the `return mainString;` in the main, this is a void method.

Answer (score 0):

like @AxelH stated in a comment, you are missing a call to the `printMenu()` function. which means that that part of code will never be executed by your program.

Comment: Sorry, I beat you, I've write the answer based on my comment. There is nothing more to said here so I thought this was enough for an answer too ;)